# React Native ScrollView not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I am new to React Native. I need to implement a ScrollView, but it doesn't work at all. I add multiple components to it and when I try to scroll, nothing happens, text goes out of my screen and I am unable to see it. Here is the code:

```
    render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView 
        behaviour = "height"
        keyboardVerticalOffset = {64}
        contentContainerStyle = {{alignItems: 'center', marginTop: '5%', flex: 1}}
      >        
          <Title style={styles.title}>Booking Confirmation</Title>
          <Image style={{
            width: '55%',
            height: '5%',
            marginTop: '5%', 
            //flex : 0.2
            }}
            source={this.getCarrierImage(this.props.currentQuote.Carrier)}
            />
          <Text style = {{padding: '5%', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Economy 2-3 days delivery</Text> 
          <Text style = {{textAlign: 'center'}}>Collection 8am-6pm, delivery in 2-3 working, delivered before 6pm</Text>

        <Text style = {{marginTop: '5%', fontWeight: 'bold', marginRight: '70%'}}>Parcel Details</Text>

        <ItemConfirmation/>

        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
        <QuoteWarning/>
      </ScrollView>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge react-native uses flex for layout properties and it does not take your percentage values. 
Try instead to to use pixels for padding,margin,width and height. And you might be a little closer. Can look it up more closesly in a few hours when I'm by my computer.